# Why do I have a badge that I apparently shouldn't have?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, badges, review

I have earned few months ago the *Copy editor* badge by editing 500+ posts in the review queue.

[image]

A week ago looking at my stats I see this (both pics were taken 1 minute ago):

[image]

Why does it says that I need 9 more edits to the *Copy Editor* badge (can be awarded only once) while I already have it. It's not a cache problem, because when I edit a post, that count is incremented correctly.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some posts you edited have since been deleted. Deleted posts do not count towards the badge, but you earned the badge *before* the posts you edited were removed.

Once earned, regular badges are forever (tag badges are taken away when you no longer meet the requirements).